# drop down handle using click in selenium with c# , i tried select class methods already

Tags: c#, selenium, dropdown

option selected properly using select class methods, from dropdown but related data of respective option could not fetched.

I use this for search table. select option for search but search action not happen for selected option

how to handle drop down using click
suggest any solution

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro]. We do not have enough information to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select tag can be used to handle the dropdown with  tag followed by  tags in the page dom, else select class will not work.

```
  IWebElement dropdown_priority = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Xpath locator")); //build webelemnt of dropdown 

  dropdown_priority.Click(); //Click on the dropdown so that all the values will popup from the dropdown
  
  //Build collection of dropdown options and pass your desired dropdown value to click on it as below
  List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements("dropdownvaluesselector");
   for(WebElement e : myElements) {
     if(e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Your_Desire_Value")) {
         e.click();
     }
```